# Alignment issues in a table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  12pt,
  landscape,
  danish
]{article}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[
  hmargin = 2.4cm,
  vmargin = 3cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\newcommand*\mc[1]{\multicolumn{3}{c}{#1}}
\newcommand*\Alignment[1]{% Justering ved `--'.
  \multicolumn{1}{r@{}}{\llap{\makebox[\widthof{--}][c]{#1}}}%
}

\def\mlrA{\hskip 2.5em}
\def\mlrB{\hskip 0.8em}
\def\mlrC{3ex}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand*\headrulewidth{0pt}
\setlength\headheight{14.5pt}
\lhead{}
\rhead{}
\cfoot{}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \textbf{\Huge Skema for skoleåret 2015--2016}
\end{center}
\vspace{5ex}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{
    c @{\mlrB}
    r @{\,--\,}
    l @{\mlrA}
    l @{\mlrB}
    l @{\mlrB}
    l @{\mlrA}
    l @{\mlrB}
    l @{\mlrB}
    l @{\mlrA}
    l @{\mlrB}
    l @{\mlrB}
    l @{\mlrA}
    l @{\mlrB}
    l @{\mlrB}
    l @{\mlrA}
    l @{\mlrB}
    l @{\mlrB}
    l
  }
   \toprule
    Lektion & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Tidspunkt} & \mc{Mandag}{\mlrA}   & \mc{Tirsdag}{\mlrA} & \mc{Onsdag}{\mlrA} & \mc{Torsdag}{\mlrA} & \mc{Fredag}{\mlrA} \\
   \midrule
    1       &  8:10 &  8:55                 &     &      &         & 7.C & F/K  & fys    & 5.A & MAT  & 09    &     &     &         & 7.C & MAT & 22     \\[\mlrC]
    2       &  8:55 &  9:40                 &     &      &         & 7.C & F/K  & fys    & 5.A & N/T  & 09    &     &     &         & 7.C & STU & 22     \\[\mlrC]
    3       & 10:00 & 10:45                 & 8.  & IDR  & hal/gym & 5.A & MAT  & 09     & 7.C & STU  & 22    & 7.C & BIO & bio     &     &     &        \\[\mlrC]
    4       & 10:45 & 11:30                 & 8.  & IDR  & hal/gym & 5.A & MAT  & 09     &     &      &       & 7.C & BIO & bio     &     &     &        \\[\mlrC]
    5       & 11:30 & 12:00                 & 5.A & FORD & 09      & 7.C & FORD & 22     & 5.A & FORD & 09    &     &     &         &     &     &        \\[\mlrC]
    6       & 12:40 & 13:25                 & 7.C & GEO  & 22      & 5.A & HIS  & 09     & 7.C & MAT  & 22    &     &     &         &     &     &        \\[\mlrC]
    7       & 13:25 & 14:10                 & 7.C & GEO  & 22      & 5.A & HIS  & 09     & 7.C & MAT  & 22    &     &     &         &     &     &        \\[\mlrC]
    8       & 14:25 & 15:10                 & 7.C & MAT  & 22      & \mc{TEAM}{\mlrA}    &     &      &       &     &     &         &     &     &        \\
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Here are the two things I have problems with:

- Is `Tidspunkt` exactly centered above the time intervals? (I'm not sure.)
- How do I center `Fredag` above the last three columns and not just the first two of the last three?

P.S. If anyone has a "better" way of typing the table, feel free to supply your suggestion(s).

**Update**

Using [Heiko Oberdiek's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261815/15874) and simplifying the code marginally, here is what I ended up with:

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  12pt,
  landscape,
  danish
]{article}



\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[
  hmargin = 2.4cm,
  vmargin = 3cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{booktabs}



\newcommand*\mc[1]{\multicolumn{3}{@{}c@{\mlrA}}{#1}}
\newcommand*\Alignment[1]{% adjustment at `--'
  \multicolumn{1}{r@{}}{\llap{\makebox[\widthof{--}][c]{#1}}}%
}

\def\mlrA{\hskip 2.5em}
\def\mlrB{\hskip 0.8em}
\def\mlrC{3ex}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand*\headrulewidth{0pt}
\setlength\headheight{14.5pt}
\lhead{}
\rhead{}
\cfoot{}



\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \textbf{\Huge Skema for skoleåret~2015--2016}
  \vspace{10ex}

  \renewcommand*\arraystretch{1.2}
  \begin{tabular}{
         c @{\mlrB}
         r @{\,--\,}
    *{5}{
         l @{\mlrA}
         l @{\mlrB}
         l @{\mlrB}
        }
         l
  }
   \toprule
    Lektion
    & \multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{\mlrA}}{Tidspunkt}
    & \mc{Mandag}
    & \mc{Tirsdag}
    & \mc{Onsdag}
    & \mc{Torsdag}
    & \multicolumn{3}{@{}c}{Fredag} \\
   \midrule
    1 &  8:10 &  8:55 &     &      &         & 7.C & F/K  & fys & 5.A & MAT  & 09 &     &     &     & 7.C & MAT & 22 \\[\mlrC]
    2 &  8:55 &  9:40 &     &      &         & 7.C & F/K  & fys & 5.A & N/T  & 09 &     &     &     & 7.C & STU & 22 \\[\mlrC]
    3 & 10:00 & 10:45 & 8.  & IDR  & hal/gym & 5.A & MAT  & 09  & 7.C & STU  & 22 & 7.C & BIO & bio &     &     &    \\[\mlrC]
    4 & 10:45 & 11:30 & 8.  & IDR  & hal/gym & 5.A & MAT  & 09  &     &      &    & 7.C & BIO & bio &     &     &    \\[\mlrC]
    5 & 11:30 & 12:00 & 5.A & FORD & 09      & 7.C & FORD & 22  & 5.A & FORD & 09 &     &     &     &     &     &    \\[\mlrC]
    6 & 12:40 & 13:25 & 7.C & GEO  & 22      & 5.A & HIS  & 09  & 7.C & MAT  & 22 &     &     &     &     &     &    \\[\mlrC]
    7 & 13:25 & 14:10 & 7.C & GEO  & 22      & 5.A & HIS  & 09  & 7.C & MAT  & 22 &     &     &     &     &     &    \\[\mlrC]
    8 & 14:25 & 15:10 & 7.C & MAT  & 22      & \mc{TEAM}        &     &      &    &     &     &     &     &     &    \\
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For 2), use `\mc{Fredag}{}`. For 1) I'd say, "yes".

Comment: Why don't you use a single (centred) column for the time intervals?

Comment: @Bernard If, for example, the third time interval was 9:55--10:45 this wouldn't be aligned properly with the other times.

Comment: Well, you can add  an `hphantom{0}` before the 9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal `\tabcolsep` is replaced between most columns by `\@{...}`. This is added to the right of the column and needs to be repeated in `\multicolumn`.
Thus, the definition for `\mc` should be:

```
\newcommand*\mc[1]{\multicolumn{3}{@{}c@{\mlrA}}{#1}}
```

And `\mc` is used with one argument only.

The last column ends with the normal `\tabcolsep` and `\mc` cannot be used, insted a normal `\multicolumn` will do:

```
\multicolumn{3}{@{}c}{Fredag}
```

And the centered title for columns 2 and 3:

```
\multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{\mlrA}}{Tidspunkt}
```

Now, the column titles should be centered correctly, see the following example.
The example also reduces `\mlrC`, the line spaces in the table body and increased `\arraystretch` to make the overall line spacing a little smoother.

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  12pt,
  landscape,
  danish
]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[
  hmargin = 2.4cm,
  vmargin = 3cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand*\mc[1]{\multicolumn{3}{@{}c@{\mlrA}}{#1}}
\newcommand*\Alignment[1]{% adjustment at `--'
  \multicolumn{1}{r@{}}{\llap{\makebox[\widthof{--}][c]{#1}}}%
}

\def\mlrA{\hskip 2.5em}
\def\mlrB{\hskip 0.8em}
\def\mlrC{1.5ex}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand*\headrulewidth{0pt}
\setlength\headheight{14.5pt}
\lhead{}
\rhead{}
\cfoot{}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \textbf{\Huge Skema for skoleåret 2015--2016}

  \vspace{5ex}

  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.3}
  \begin{tabular}{
    c @{\mlrB}
    r @{\,--\,}
    l @{\mlrA}
    l @{\mlrB}
    l @{\mlrB}
    l @{\mlrA}
    l @{\mlrB}
    l @{\mlrB}
    l @{\mlrA}
    l @{\mlrB}
    l @{\mlrB}
    l @{\mlrA}
    l @{\mlrB}
    l @{\mlrB}
    l @{\mlrA}
    l @{\mlrB}
    l @{\mlrB}
    l
  }
   \toprule
    Lektion
    & \multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{\mlrA}}{Tidspunkt}
    & \mc{Mandag}
    & \mc{Tirsdag}
    & \mc{Onsdag}
    & \mc{Torsdag}
    & \multicolumn{3}{@{}c}{Fredag} \\
   \midrule
    1  &  8:10 &  8:55  &     &      &         & 7.C & F/K  & fys  & 5.A & MAT  & 09  &     &     &      & 7.C & MAT & 22 \\[\mlrC]
    2  &  8:55 &  9:40  &     &      &         & 7.C & F/K  & fys  & 5.A & N/T  & 09  &     &     &      & 7.C & STU & 22 \\[\mlrC]
    3  & 10:00 & 10:45  & 8.  & IDR  & hal/gym & 5.A & MAT  & 09   & 7.C & STU  & 22  & 7.C & BIO & bio  &     &     &    \\[\mlrC]
    4  & 10:45 & 11:30  & 8.  & IDR  & hal/gym & 5.A & MAT  & 09   &     &      &     & 7.C & BIO & bio  &     &     &    \\[\mlrC]
    5  & 11:30 & 12:00  & 5.A & FORD & 09      & 7.C & FORD & 22   & 5.A & FORD & 09  &     &     &      &     &     &    \\[\mlrC]
    6  & 12:40 & 13:25  & 7.C & GEO  & 22      & 5.A & HIS  & 09   & 7.C & MAT  & 22  &     &     &      &     &     &    \\[\mlrC]
    7  & 13:25 & 14:10  & 7.C & GEO  & 22      & 5.A & HIS  & 09   & 7.C & MAT  & 22  &     &     &      &     &     &    \\[\mlrC]
    8  & 14:25 & 15:10  & 7.C & MAT  & 22      & \mc{TEAM}         &     &      &     &     &     &      &     &     &    \\
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Since the table title belongs to the table, the `table` environment is removed and the table is put into the `center` environment with the table title. Alternatively, `\centering` could be used, when additional vertical spaces of the `center` environment is not needed/wanted.

Comment: The `tabular` should be in the same `center` environment as the title.

Comment: The `TEAM` entry is not aligned properly but I've fixed that myself.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, the updated answer provides a cleanup for the centering stuff.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Thanks, I noticed while cleaning up the centering stuff and the updated answer also fixes this.