# Horizontal alignment problems in table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

This is a follow-up question to "[Alignment issues in a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261812/alignment-issues-in-a-table)".

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  12pt,
  landscape,
  danish
]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[
  hmargin = 2.4cm,
  vmargin = 3cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand*\mc[1]{\multicolumn{3}{@{}c@{\mlrA}}{#1}}
\newcommand*\MC[1]{\multicolumn{3}{@{}c@{\mlrA}}{$\langle$#1$\rangle$}}
\newcommand*\Alignment[1]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{r@{}}{\llap{\makebox[\widthof{--}][c]{#1}}}}

\def\mlrA{\hskip 2.5em}
\def\mlrB{\hskip 0.8em}
\def\mlrC{3ex}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand*\headrulewidth{0pt}
\setlength\headheight{14.5pt}
\lhead{}
\rhead{}
\cfoot{}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \textbf{\Huge Skema~2015--2016}
  \vspace{10ex}

  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \begin{tabular}{
         S[table-format = 2] @{\mlrB}
         r @{\,--\,}
    *{5}{
         l @{\mlrA}
         l @{\mlrB}
         l @{\mlrB}
        }
         l
  }
   \toprule
    {Lektion}
    & \multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{\mlrA}}{Tidspunkt}
    & \multicolumn{3}{@{}c}{Mandag}
    & \multicolumn{3}{@{}c}{Tirsdag}
    & \mc{Onsdag}
    & \multicolumn{3}{@{}c}{Torsdag}
    & \multicolumn{3}{@{}c}{Fredag} \\
   \midrule
     1 &  8:10 &  8:55 &     &      &         & 7.C & F/K  & fys & 5.A & MAT  & 09 &     &     &     & 7.C & MAT & 22 \\[\mlrC]
     2 &  8:55 &  9:40 &     &      &         & 7.C & F/K  & fys & 5.A & N/T  & 09 &     &     &     & 7.C & STU & 22 \\[\mlrC]
     3 & 10:00 & 10:45 & 8.  & IDR  & hal/gym & 5.A & MAT  & 09  & 7.C & STU  & 22 & 7.C & BIO & bio & \MC{Fagdag}    \\[\mlrC]
     4 & 10:45 & 11:30 & 8.  & IDR  & hal/gym & 5.A & MAT  & 09  &     &      &    & 7.C & BIO & bio & \MC{Fagdag}    \\[\mlrC]
     5 & 11:30 & 12:00 & 5.A & FORD & 09      & 7.C & FORD & 22  & 5.A & FORD & 09 &     &     &     & \MC{Fagdag}    \\[\mlrC]
     6 & 12:40 & 13:25 & 7.C & GEO  & 22      & 5.A & HIS  & 09  & 7.C & MAT  & 22 &     &     &     & \MC{Fagdag}    \\[\mlrC]
     7 & 13:25 & 14:10 & 7.C & GEO  & 22      & 5.A & HIS  & 09  & 7.C & MAT  & 22 &     &     &     & \MC{Fagdag}    \\[\mlrC]
     8 & 14:25 & 15:10 & 7.C & MAT  & 22      &     &      &     &     &      &    & \mc{5.~årgang}  & \multicolumn{3}{@{}c@{\mlrA}}{($\langle$Fagdag$\rangle$)} \\[\mlrC]
     9 & 15:10 & 16:10 & \mc{7.~årgang}       & \mc{Fløj}        &     &      &    & \mc{5.~årgang}  &     &     &    \\[\mlrC]
    10 & 16:00 & 17:00 &     &      &         & \mc{Fløj}        &     &      &    &     &     &     &     &     &    \\
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

How to I center `<Fagdag>` (and `(<Fagdag>)`) in the last column?

I guess the problem is do to a simple error by me but I can't figure out what it is.

**Update**

Is anyone creates an answer to my question (Sunilkumar KS has given the solution in an comment), I'll accept it and we can remove the question from the unanswered list.

Comment: Understand that those were coded in \MC command, which is suffixed with a horizontal skip (\mlrA) in \multicolumn.

Please try with the following redefinition of \MC, where I removed \mlrA command.

\newcommand*\MC[1]{\multicolumn{3}{@{}c@{}}{$\langle$#1$\rangle$}}

Comment: @SunilkumarKS Then the text is pushed too much to the right.

Comment: Now I noted that the columns are separated with horizontal spaces with \mlrA and \mlrB.  I have slightly amended the code as below, please try this one.

\newcommand*\MC[1]{\multicolumn{3}{@{}c@{\mlrB}}{$\langle$#1$\rangle$}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

your last four columns are

```
   l spaceA 
   l spaceB 
   l spaceB
   l \tabcolsep
```

So your `\multicolumn{3}` needs `@{}` on the left so no space is added to the left (the space B from the preceding column will be there) and then a nothing on the right to match the column specified space so you need

```
 \newcommand*\MC[1]{\multicolumn{3}{@{}c}{$\langle$#1$\rangle$}}
```

The whole document:

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  12pt,
  landscape,
  danish
]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[
  hmargin = 2.4cm,
  vmargin = 3cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand*\mc[1]{\multicolumn{3}{@{}c@{\mlrA}}{#1}}
\newcommand*\MC[1]{\multicolumn{3}{@{}c}{$\langle$#1$\rangle$}}
\newcommand*\Alignment[1]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{r@{}}{\llap{\makebox[\widthof{--}][c]{#1}}}}

\def\mlrA{\hskip 2.5em}
\def\mlrB{\hskip 0.8em}
\def\mlrC{3ex}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand*\headrulewidth{0pt}
\setlength\headheight{14.5pt}
\lhead{}
\rhead{}
\cfoot{}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \textbf{\Huge Skema~2015--2016}
  \vspace{10ex}

  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \begin{tabular}{
         S[table-format = 2] @{\mlrB}
         r @{\,--\,}
    *{5}{
         l @{\mlrA}
         l @{\mlrB}
         l @{\mlrB}
        }
         l
  }
   \toprule
    {Lektion}
    & \multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{\mlrA}}{Tidspunkt}
    & \multicolumn{3}{@{}c}{Mandag}
    & \multicolumn{3}{@{}c}{Tirsdag}
    & \mc{Onsdag}
    & \multicolumn{3}{@{}c}{Torsdag}
    & \multicolumn{3}{@{}c}{Fredag} \\
   \midrule
     1 &  8:10 &  8:55 &     &      &         & 7.C & F/K  & fys & 5.A & MAT  & 09 &     &     &     & 7.C & MAT & 22 \\[\mlrC]
     2 &  8:55 &  9:40 &     &      &         & 7.C & F/K  & fys & 5.A & N/T  & 09 &     &     &     & 7.C & STU & 22 \\[\mlrC]
     3 & 10:00 & 10:45 & 8.  & IDR  & hal/gym & 5.A & MAT  & 09  & 7.C & STU  & 22 & 7.C & BIO & bio & \MC{Fagdag}    \\[\mlrC]
     4 & 10:45 & 11:30 & 8.  & IDR  & hal/gym & 5.A & MAT  & 09  &     &      &    & 7.C & BIO & bio & \MC{Fagdag}    \\[\mlrC]
     5 & 11:30 & 12:00 & 5.A & FORD & 09      & 7.C & FORD & 22  & 5.A & FORD & 09 &     &     &     & \MC{Fagdag}    \\[\mlrC]
     6 & 12:40 & 13:25 & 7.C & GEO  & 22      & 5.A & HIS  & 09  & 7.C & MAT  & 22 &     &     &     & \MC{Fagdag}    \\[\mlrC]
     7 & 13:25 & 14:10 & 7.C & GEO  & 22      & 5.A & HIS  & 09  & 7.C & MAT  & 22 &     &     &     & \MC{Fagdag}    \\[\mlrC]
     8 & 14:25 & 15:10 & 7.C & MAT  & 22      &     &      &     &     &      &    & \mc{5.~årgang}  & \multicolumn{3}{@{}c@{\mlrB}}{($\langle$Fagdag$\rangle$)} \\[\mlrC]
     9 & 15:10 & 16:10 & \mc{7.~årgang}       & \mc{Fløj}        &     &      &    & \mc{5.~årgang}  &     &     &    \\[\mlrC]
    10 & 16:00 & 17:00 &     &      &         & \mc{Fløj}        &     &      &    &     &     &     &     &     &    \\
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```