# Horizontal alignment problems in table, v2

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

This is another follow-up question to "[Alignment issues in a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261812/alignment-issues-in-a-table)".

**Code**

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  12pt,
  landscape,
  danish
]{article}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[
  hmargin = 1.561cm,
  vmargin = 3cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{microtype}


\newcommand*\mcA[1]{\multicolumn{3}{@{}c@{\mlrA}}{#1}}
\newcommand*\mcB[1]{\multicolumn{3}{@{}l@{\mlrA}}{#1}}
\newcommand*\mcC[1]{\multicolumn{3}{@{}c@{\mlrB}}{#1}}
\newcommand*\Alignment[1]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{r@{}}{\llap{\makebox[\widthof{--}][c]{#1}}}}

\def\mlrA{\hskip 2.5em}
\def\mlrB{\hskip 0.8em}
\def\mlrC{3ex}

\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding = T1}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand*\headrulewidth{0pt}
\setlength\headheight{14.5pt}
\lhead{}
\rhead{}
\cfoot{}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \textbf{\Huge Skema~2015--2016}
  \vspace{10ex}

  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \begin{tabular}{
         S[table-format = 2] @{\mlrB}
         r @{\,--\,}
    *{5}{
         l @{\mlrA}
         l @{\mlrB}
         l @{\mlrB}
        }
         l
  }
   \toprule
    {Lektion}
    & \multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{\mlrA}}{Tidspunkt}
    & \mcA{Mandag}
    & \mcA{Tirsdag}
    & \mcA{Onsdag}
    & \mcA{Torsdag}
    & \mcA{Fredag} \\
   \midrule
     1 &  8:10 &  8:55 &     &      &          & 7.C & F/K  & fys                & 5.A & MAT  & 09 &     &     &           & 7.C & MAT & 22 \\[\mlrC]
     2 &  8:55 &  9:40 &     &      &          & 7.C & F/K  & fys                & 5.A & N/T  & 09 &     &     &           & 7.C & STU & 22 \\[\mlrC]
     3 & 10:00 & 10:45 & 8.  & IDR  & hal/gym  & 5.A & MAT  & 09                 & 7.C & STU  & 22 & 7.C & BIO & bio       & \mcC{Fagdag}   \\[\mlrC]
     4 & 10:45 & 11:30 & 8.  & IDR  & hal/gym  & 5.A & MAT  & 09                 &     &      &    & 7.C & BIO & bio       & \mcC{Fagdag}   \\[\mlrC]
     5 & 11:30 & 12:00 & 5.A & FORD & 09       & 7.C & FORD & 22                 & 5.A & FORD & 09 &     &     &           & \mcC{Fagdag}   \\[\mlrC]
     6 & 12:40 & 13:25 & 7.C & GEO  & 22       & 5.A & HIS  & 09                 & 7.C & MAT  & 22 &     &     &           & \mcC{Fagdag}   \\[\mlrC]
     7 & 13:25 & 14:10 & 7.C & GEO  & 22       & 5.A & HIS  & 09                 & 7.C & MAT  & 22 &     &     &           & \mcC{Fagdag}   \\[\mlrC]
     8 & 14:25 & 15:10 & 7.C & MAT  & 22       &     &      &                    &     &      &    & \mcB{Møde: Rød fløj}  & \multicolumn{3}{@{}c@{\mlrB}}{(Fagdag)} \\[\mlrC]
     9 & 15:10 & 16:10 & \mcA{Møde: 7.~årgang} & \mcB{(Møde, koord.: Hvid fløj)} &     &      &    & \mcB{Møde: 5.~årgang} &     &     &    \\[\mlrC]
    10 & 16:00 & 17:00 &     &      &          & \mcB{(Møde, intern: Hvid fløj)} &     &      &    &     &     &           &     &     &    \\
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

**Question**

How do I center the marked text relative to `Tirsdag` above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my opinion it is worth to rethinking  concept of table.  Maybe the problems of centering would be easier managed, if the columns consisted with three "subcolumns" will be typeset as separate tables and included to main table into belonging multi row cells spanning most of belonging column.

The code considered aforementioned consideration gives:

[image]

where vertical lines is put intentionally to show how well are columns centered. They also minimize subjective impression, how well columns are centered. In final version they can be omitted.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,landscape,
%               danish
               ]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[hmargin = 1.561cm,vmargin = 3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{microtype}

\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding = T1}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\textbf{\Huge Skema~2015--2016}
\vspace{10ex}

\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{7pt}    
\begin{tabular}{|@{\ }S[table-format = 2] 
                    |r @{\,--\,}l        
                    *{5}{|c}@{\ }|}
    \toprule
{Lektion}
    &       \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Tidspunkt}
            &       Mandag
                    &       Tirsdag
                            &       Onsdag
                                    &       Torsdag
                                            &   Fredag  \\
    \midrule
 1 &  8:10 &  8:55  &       &   \multirow{7}*{
    \begin{tabular}{rll}
    7.C &   F/K     &   fys \\
    7.C &   F/K     &   fys \\
    7.C &   MAT     &   09  \\
    7.C &   MAT     &   09  \\
    7.C &   FORD    &   09  \\
    7.C &   HIS     &   09  \\
    7.C &   HIS     &   09        
    \end{tabular}     }               &   \multirow{7}*{
            \begin{tabular}{rll}
            5.A &   MAT     &   fys \\
            5.A &   N/T     &   fys \\
            5.A &   STU     &   09  \\
                &&  \vphantom{09}   \\
            5.A &   FORD    &   09  \\
            5.A &   MAT     &   09  \\
            5.A &   MAT     &   09
            \end{tabular}     }           &       &   \multirow{2}*{
                    \begin{tabular}{rll}
                    7.C &   MAT     &   22 \\
                    7.C &   MAT     &   22
                    \end{tabular}     }                     \\%end of row
 2 &  8:55  &  9:40 &   \multirow{6}*{
    \begin{tabular}{rll}
    8.  &   IDR     &   fys \\
    8.  &   IDR     &   fys \\
    8.  &   FORD    &   09  \\
    8.  &   GEO     &   09  \\
    8.  &   GEO     &   09  \\
    8.  &   MAT     &   09  
    \end{tabular}     }     &       &       &       &           \\
 3 & 10:00  & 10:45 &       &       &       &   \multirow{2}*{
            \begin{tabular}{rll}
            7.C &   BIO     &   bio \\
            7.C &   BIO     &   bio
            \end{tabular}     }         
        &   Fagdag  \\
 4 & 10:45  & 11:30 &       &       &       &       &   Fagdag  \\ 
 5 & 11:30  & 12:00 &       &       &       &       &   Fagdag  \\ 
 6 & 12:40  & 13:25 &       &       &       &       &   Fagdag  \\ 
 7 & 13:25  & 14:10 &       &       &       &       &   Fagdag  \\ 
 8 & 14:25  & 15:10 &       &       &       &       &   Fagdag  \\ 
 9 & 15:10  & 16:10 &   Møde: 7.~årgang
                            &   (Møde, koord.: Hvid fløj)
                                    &       &   Møde: Rød fløj
                                                    &           \\
10 & 16:00  & 17:00 &      &   (Møde, koord.: Hvid fløj)
                                    &       &   Møde: 5.~årgang
                                                    &           \\
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
    \end{document}
```

In code I omitted all unused packages in preamble, all definition of distances and `multicolumns`, since they are not needed anymore and added package `multirow`.

For distance between rows can be set by `\arraystretch` To may test value `1.5` is good choice. Similarly the distances between columns are set by `\tabcolsep`. The selection of `7pt` seems to be adequate.

It is possible, that contents of particular cell is not correct. Make an error in copy past is quit obvious :-(.

I hope that I give an another view how to solve your problem.

Comment: This looks good. There is missing a vertical line between `Tidspunkt` and `mandag`.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg, I see now. In only one `multicolumn` anvironment it should be added after `c`:  `\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Tidspunkt}`. I will correct code accordingly and also one typing typo. New image is on the way :-)

Comment: @SvendTveskæg, if you člike to have vertical lines in your table, than the `booktabs` rules aren't the best choice. As you can see, they are not conected. To be connected, than you have tho choices: replace `booktabs` rules with `\hline` or change table environment. For example use (old good) `mdwtab` or `tabu`. This changes doesn't caise a lot of works ...

Comment: There is another, newer option whose name I always forget. @SvendTveskæg also. But I would not use `tabu` under any circumstances short of dire life-or-death emergency. (A madman threatens to blow up the city if you don't finish the table and `tabu` is the only way to complete it in time. That kind of thing. After all, who cares if the code works in a month's time? By then, you can hope the madman will be safely behind bars. Failing that, you have a month to get yourself safely behind bars.)

Comment: But `booktabs` and vertical rules just do not agree. @SvendTveskæg have you read the package's documentation? The author is incredibly clear on this point.

Comment: @cfr If you can give a "better" answer, I will gladly see your solution. (I read the documentation a long time ago.)

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Delete all the vertical rules?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Your image in the question doesn't even seem to have vertical rules. So why don't you just remove them from the code in this answer? I'm not really clear what the objection to John Kormylo's answer was. Since my 'better' very likely isn't yours, without knowing all that, I'd be wasting my time.

Comment: @cfr, to my taste, table without vertical lines is more beautiful (as was proposed in my first version of answer), but if if vertical lines are so desirable, than the `booktabs` rules is wrong choice. I ttry to show this in my answer! I hope that with mention of possible alternative packages -- both are not maintained any more -- I didn't do mortal sin :-)

Comment: @Zarko No, no. I agree. I would not, however, recommend `tabu`. The author has promised backwards-incompatible changes and refuses to fix serious bugs in the meantime. At some point, code using `tabu` will break. Until then, code using `tabu` has bugs.

Comment: @cfr "Better answer" was probably a bad phrase. Do you have _another_ solution?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Why can't you not use vertical rules?

Comment: @cfr I can use vertical lines but I prefer not to. Where have I ever said that I can't? `:-)`

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Well if Zarko doesn't like vertical lines and you don't like vertical lines, why are you (whichever of you) trying to get vertical lines in a `booktabs` tabular? Why not just remove them? But then, what was wrong with the first answer? I'm just extremely confused at this point.

Comment: @cfr Look at the `Tirsdag` column at the first answer.